# Client unable to establish connection when server migrated from socket.io 0.9 to 1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Need help migrating socket.IO 0.9 to 1.0.
The follow 1.0 codes runs without error but it is a complete silence when my iOS client tries to connect to the server as per usual. The iOS client will get error status 400 whenever it is trying to establish socket connection with the server.

// Socket.IO 0.9 implementation

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = express(); // better instead
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
var io = require ('socket.io').listen(server.listen(port));
io.configure(function () { 
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
    io.set("close timeout", 10);
    io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
        // process handshake
    });
    io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    ...
});
```

// Socket.IO 1.0 implementation

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = express(); // better instead
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
var io = require ('socket.io')(server.listen(port));
io.use(function(socket, next){
    // never triggered!
    next();
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // never triggered!
});
```

Comment: Is the client updated to use socket.io 1.0 also?

Comment: argh! didn't realise the iOS client only works with 0.9....thanks!